# Using database instead of in memory store Identity server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, identityserver4

Please guide me how we can customize identityserver 4 to  use database instead of in memory store.

List of class that need to be overridden and how they are to be configured

Comment: Did you get something? I tried to ask this on gitter with the identityserver4 community. But nobody seems to reply anything constructive on it. I believe since IdSrv is just now in its beta, that's why these things are in process of getting ported to the identityserver4. We will have to wait for RCs of it for these things.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but it has no answer and someone else may stumble upon this like I did and need a solution.

Here is a [walk through guide for setting up database usage via entity framework](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html) that is a part of the Identity Server 4 docs. If you are just getting started with Identity Server there is a template IS4 project that can be set up to use database stores via entity framework out of the box. Go [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Templates) and see the info for the `dotnet new is4ef` template

---

### Converting in-memory store to Database store

If you are already using an in-memory store Identity Server 4 project, then basically the walk through above will have you install the `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework` Nuget package. Then you will either need to run EF Migrations to create you database to store the Identity Server configuration and operational data, or optionally set the database up yourself with the `ConfigurationDb.sql` and the `PersistedGrantsDb.sql` scripts located [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/src/EntityFramework.Storage/migrations/SqlServer/Migrations) (remove migration commands and tweak as needed).

The next step is to replace the current calls to `AddInMemoryClients`, `AddInMemoryIdentityResources`, and `AddInMemoryApiResources` in the `ConfigureServices` method in ***Startup.cs***. You will replace these calls with new calls to the `AddConfigurationStore` and `AddOperationalStore` extensions on the `IServiceCollection.AddIdentityServer` extension method. Like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //other configuration code ...
    
    string connectionString = "your DB connectionString";
    
    services.AddIdentityServer()
        // this adds the config data DB support (clients, resources, CORS)
        .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        })
        // this adds the operational data DB support (codes, tokens, consents)
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        });
}
```